# Use ssh keys only where configured

Tags: unix, ssh

I have quite a couple of SSH keys in my `.ssh` directory, each for one or two hosts. The mapping of key -> server is configured in `.ssh/config`, yet ssh tries every key on every server I want to log in.

For servers where I do not have a key but want to login with a password that results in too many authentication failures and I have to manually specify `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no`.

Can I tell ssh to only use keys where configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option to limit the identity files :

> **IdentitiesOnly**
>
> Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity files configured in the ssh_config files, even
>   if ssh-agent(1) offers more identities. The argument to this keyword
>   must be ''yes'' or ''no''. This option is intended for situations
>   where ssh-agent offers many different identities. The default is
>   ''no''.

And this option to turn off the use of public keys when using a password :

> **RSAAuthentication**
>
> Specifies whether to try RSA authentication. The argument to this keyword must be ''yes'' or ''no''. RSA authentication
>   will only be attempted if the identity file exists, or an
>   authentication agent is running. The default is ''yes''. Note that
>   this option applies to protocol version 1 only.

Source : http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: Thank you! I already used `IdentitiesOnly` but did not know about `RSAAuthentication`